# Python COM Server: Accessing Singleton

Tags: python, com, singleton, pythoncom

I need to access the data of one single object from different python processes via COM.

In a similar question here on stackoverflow, it was suggested to let the client create multiple COM objects, but let those communicate with a single object implemention... but I really have no idea how to do that.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!
Malte

Comment: Basically, you keep the server's singleton private, and you provide fresh objects that just redirect method calls to the singleton. If you have already achieved a server that provides a singleton, this should be easy in comparison.